# Typescript custom decorators : context of this

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator, aop

I am creating a custom decorator that will run decorated functions on RxJS events.

So far so good : my issue comes when the function is actually ran : the context of the `this` object is lost.

I've been looking for a solution for the past day but I can't seem to find it.

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzf1ch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) reproducing the issue. The goal is to see `Angular` in the console, coming from `this.name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're trying call a method on the instance of decorated class in your decorator. However, class decorators do not work this way. They are called when the class is *defined*, not when it's instantiated, so you cannot call anything with instances of your class.

Here's your [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mh6l6e?file=src/app/hello.component.ts).  I'm extending your class and calling the method in the constructor of the extended class, so that it is called whenever objects of the decorated class are instantiated.

Comment: I see, is that going to be an issue to extend the constructor ?

Comment: And it doesn't seem that your solution is very lint compliant ... My project beign very strict about that, I won't be able to use it. But thank you for the piece of code, I learnt something out of it, so +1 !

Comment: I managed to make it TSLint compliant, is it possible to get the parameters of the initial constructor to add it to the `super` call ? I tried with `constructor.arguments` but it throws `'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`

Comment: @trichetriche You can accept `...args` in the subclass constructor and call `super(...args)`

Comment: but where to get the `args` ?

Comment: @trichetriche declare `...args` as a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters)

Comment: But where ? The only place I can is the new constructor, and it doesn't have parameters

Comment: Oh, you actually can ! didn't know that. Thank you for all the answers !

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code it will work. Hear you have only change this to constructor.

```
function HelloWorld(): ClassDecorator {
  return function(constructor) {
    constructor.prototype.HelloWorld.apply(new constructor(), null);
  };
}
```

Comment: `Hello world, name is
HelloComponent`

Comment: I have updated the code and how it displays **Hello world, name is  Angular**.Added new constructor()  in stand of constructor

Comment: This would work for a simple class, but by doing that, I lose every memory reference to the previous object because I instantiate a new one. Besides, in the case of services, which are singletons, this means I am breaking the design pattern. But it works and it's my fault for not specifying those points, so I'll remove my downvote !

Answer (score -1):

My custom way to convey the context for method in map :)

```
return class extends constructor {
            constructor(...args) {
                super(...args);
                if(constructor.processCallbackMap){
                    Array.from(constructor.processCallbackMap).map(([key, value]) = {
                        constructor.processCallbackMap.set(key, value.bind(this));
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

in https://netbasal.com/inspiration-for-custom-decorators-in-angular-95aeb87f072c
there are no

```
constructor.prototype.HelloWord.apply(this, null);
```

just comment the line your app work

the cosntructor.prototype is using to be possible use of ngOnInit, ngOnChanges...

the e.g. show in the page is

```
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
export function NgLog() : ClassDecorator {
  return function ( constructor : any ) {
    if( !environment.production ) {
      // You can add/remove events for your needs
      const LIFECYCLE_HOOKS = [
        'ngOnInit',
        'ngOnChanges',
        'ngOnDestroy'
      ];
      const component = constructor.name;

      LIFECYCLE_HOOKS.forEach(hook => {
        const original = constructor.prototype[hook];

        constructor.prototype[hook] = function ( ...args ) {
          console.log(`%c ${component} - ${hook}`, `color: #4CAF50; font-weight: bold`, ...args);
          original && original.apply(this, args);
        }
      });
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: The function name is irrelevant. I saw his piece and learnt decorators from it. What he does is that he adds a wanted behavior to a function. What I want to do is call the said function, not extend it.